# dynamically change column data dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

http://jsfiddle.net/c3coukLz/

```
t = $('#example').DataTable();
$('tbody tr').click(function() {
  $(this).find('td:last').text('B');

  //get back data
  var tr = $(this);
  var row = t.row(tr); // worked!
  console.log(row.data()); // won't work
});
```

Everything seems to work but when I do row.data(), it got me back the old data before DOM manipulation. It seems like I have to somehow 'update' the datatable. How to manipulate column data programmatically using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cell](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) for altering data. indicate the row and column of the cell to modify. Use `data` to assign the new value and `draw` to refresh the table.

**Try this code:**

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   //get back data
   var row = t.row( this );
   t.cell(row, 4).data("B").draw();
   console.log(row.data());
});
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/c3coukLz/1/